# Unfinished comments seem to get auto-submitted

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

I sometimes find myself starting to write a comment, then deciding otherwise and leaving the page with the unfinished comment still in the input field.

However, I've had it 2 or 3 times now that the comment got posted anyway.

Is this a bug?

All the instances I noticed were on Meta if that makes a difference; in all cases, the respective page/tab was open for a long time (a couple of minutes).

Comment: Never happened to me.

Comment: I've noticed that the `Add Comment` button does respond to the enter key... maybe you identically hit enter when the box had focus?

Comment: @psu - that happens to me all the time when working with dual screens... First world problems :-P

Comment: I've had it happen a couple of times that I was writing a comment, then a dialog popped up, and when closing the dialog by pressing the return key, that additionally posted the unfinished comment.

Comment: I always click to close this stuff, so it seems unlikely I pressed Enter. I can't easily repro the problem though - I just left a comment open for 20 minutes and left the page, nothing happened

Comment: Never seen this unless I also accidentally hit "enter". The alternative - inadvertently navigating away while writing a comment, thus losing it completely - happens to me fairly often.

Comment: I reported a [similar but not identical issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244023).